# How to set a field in yaml which path contains forward slash

Tags: yaml, yq

How can I replace a field in a YAML file using the command line tool `yq` (version v4.30.6) which path contains a forward slash `/`?

My YAML file `test.yaml` looks like

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    a.b.c/d: aaa
  namespace: bbb
```

I am able to replace the content of the field "metadata.namespace" but am failing to apply the same logic to "metadata.annotations.a.b.c/d" as shown below.

```bash
> MY_VARIABLE=xxx
> cat test.yaml | yq '(.metadata.namespace)|='\""$MY_VARIABLE"\" | yq '(.metadata.annotations.a.b.c/d)|='\""$MY_VARIABLE"\"
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    a.b.c/d: aaa
    a:
      b:
        c/d: xxx
  namespace: xxx
```

I would like to replace `aaa` with `xxx`. How can I do this with `yq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote identifiers if they contain special characters ([docs](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/traverse-read#special-characters)). Also, use `env` to access values from outside (environment) variables ([docs](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-string-environment-variable)).

```bash
MY_VARIABLE=xxx yq '.metadata.annotations."a.b.c/d" = env(MY_VARIABLE)' test.yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    a.b.c/d: xxx
  namespace: bbb
```